# Monarch Syntax Highlighting and Multi-line Patterns

Tags: syntax-highlighting, monaco-editor

Right now I am trying to write a syntax highlighter for my custom language using [Monarch](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html). However, in my language (and many others), sometimes the syntax highlighting could change based on what's on the next line. For example, here is one such case in Javascript:

```js
fn(foo     // here, foo is an argument
   => bar)

fn(foo     // but here, foo is an identifier
   + bar)
```

Unfortunately it seems like by default, monarch regexes work line by line. So I can't figure out how I would achieve this. Is there a way to enable multi-line regexes in Monarch? Or is there some other way to solve this?